# Node/Express doesn't load CSS on 500 error page

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, pug

For my error page, I use

```
// 500 error
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(err.stack);
    res.render("error", {
        status: err.status || 500,
        error: err,
        title: config.pageTitles.error,
        ENV: app.get('ENV')
    });
});
```

My error page is a jade template that looks:

```
extends base
block body
    body(class="gray-bg")
        div(class="middle-box text-center animated fadeInDown")
            h1 500
            h3(class="font-bold") Internal Server Error
            div(class="error-desc")
                p   The server encountered something unexpected that didn't allow it to complete the request. We apologize.
```

My other normal pages are

```
extends base
block content
    #application
```

My problem is when I get 500 error, the CSS is not loaded; however, if I load the page `error` on a normal page, then the CSS IS loaded. It seems like the `app.use` for the error causes this.

Help is appreciated

Comment: check any relative paths to make sure they point to where they should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically when assets aren't being loaded (e.g. server returns a 404 for the asset) the problem has to do with the use of (relative) paths.

Try either using an absolute path (in your template) for your CSS file and/or use your browser's web development tools to check what the requested asset path is and fix the appropriate relative path (e.g. adding `..` where appropriate to get to the correct path).